# Checking my softmax deriviation logic

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, jacobian, neural-networks

I wanted to check my derivation logic as I see so many places doing it online slightly differently. So I will show you my derivation and have my questions at the end:

where $n$ is the size of the vector $z$. $S$ is the softmax function.

\begin{eqnarray*}
  {z}  = \left(\begin{array}{c}
    z_0\\
    z_1\\
    \vdots\\
    z_n
  \end{array}\right) &  & {a}  = S ({z}) =
  \left(\begin{array}{c}
    S (z_0)\\
    S (z_1)\\
    \vdots\\
    S (z_n)
  \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
    \dfrac{e^{z_0 }}{{\sum^n_{j = 0}}  e^{z_j }}\\
    \dfrac{e^{z_1 }}{{\sum^n_{j = 0}}  e^{z_j }}\\
    \vdots\\
    \dfrac{e^{z_n }}{{\sum^n_{j = 0}}  e^{z_j }}
  \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
    a_0\\
    a_1\\
    \vdots\\
    a_n
  \end{array}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

I want the derivative $da/dz$. So I can take the derivative of each element.

\begin{eqnarray*}
  & \dfrac{d {a} }{d {z} } =
  \left(\begin{array}{c}
    \dfrac{d a_0 }{d {z} }\\
    \dfrac{d a_1 }{d {z} }\\
    \vdots\\
    \dfrac{d a_n }{d {z} }
  \end{array}\right) & 
\end{eqnarray*}

For element $j$ in $da/dz$ I have:

$$\dfrac{d {a_j}  }{d {z} } = \dfrac{d S
({z}_j)}{d {z }} = \dfrac{d \left( \dfrac{e^{z_j 
}}{e^{z_0 } + e^{{z_1} } + \cdots + e^{z_n }} \right)}{d
{z} }$$

As the derivative $da_j/dz$ contains multiple independent variables $(z_0,z_1,…,z_n)$ I will take the total derivative as the sum of all partial derivatives where $k$ is the element in $z$ with which the derivative is in respect to.

\begin{eqnarray*}
  & \dfrac{d a_j}{d {z} } = {\sum^n_{k = 0}} 
  \dfrac{d a_j }{{d z_k} } = \dfrac{d {a_j} }{{d
  z_0} } + \dfrac{d {a_j }}{{d z_1} } + \ldots +
  \dfrac{d {a_j} }{{d z_n} } & 
\end{eqnarray*}
So now I have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
  & \dfrac{d {a} }{d {z} } =
  \left(\begin{array}{c}
    \dfrac{d a_0 }{d {z} }\\
    \dfrac{d a_1 }{d {z} }\\
    \vdots\\
    \dfrac{d a_n }{d {z} }
  \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
    \dfrac{d {a_0} }{{d z_0} } + \dfrac{d
    {a_0 }}{{d z_1} } + \ldots + \dfrac{d
    {a_j}_0}{{d z_n} }\\
    \dfrac{d {a_1} }{{d z_0} } + \dfrac{d
    {a_1 }}{{d z_1} } + \ldots + \dfrac{d
    {a_1}}{{d z_n} }\\
    \vdots\\
    \dfrac{d {a_n} }{{d z_0} } + \dfrac{d
    {a_n }}{{d z_1} } + \ldots + \dfrac{d {a_n}
    }{{d z_n} }
  \end{array}\right) & 
\end{eqnarray*}

From here I am able to derive all the partial derivatives and get the final derivative. I will skip the full working here as I am comfortable this is correct with what is online.

when $k=j$:
$$\dfrac{d a_j}{d z_k} = \dfrac{d a_j}{d z_j} = a_j  (1 -
a_j)$$

when $k≠j$:
$$\dfrac{d a_j}{d z_k} = - a_j a_k$$

This gives the final answer:

$$\dfrac{d {a} }{d {z} }  = \left(\begin{array}{c}
  a_0  (1 - a_0) + - a_0 a_1 + \ldots + - a_0 a_n\\
  - a_1 a_0 + a_1  (1 - a_1) + \ldots + - a_1 a_n\\
  \vdots\\
  - a_n a_0 + - a_n a_1 + \ldots + a_n  (1 - a_n)
\end{array}\right)$$

My questions:

1. Is it correct when I take $da/dz$ and then instead do it element wise $da_j/dz$. Then furthermore is it correct that I take $da_j/dz$ and compute it as the sum of partial derivatives $da_j/dz_0 + da_j/dz_1 + ... + da_j/dz_n$? I see some other sources doing it differently or skipping steps so I am not so sure.
2. Why do I see so many places online computing the Jacobian matrix for this? I understand that the Jacobian matrix contains all the partial derivatives but as far as I can see the actual derivative is the sum of all the rows in the Jacobian matrix and I think it only confuses matters.
3. Often I see online it is said that the Jacobian matrix IS the derivative $da/dz$. Is that correct? If it is correct, then what have I done? and furthermore how can I use a matrix for backpropigation, I thought it had to be a vector.

Thank you for any help, I think I'm close to completely understanding this derivation and hope to implement it into my neural network.

Comment: The expression $S(z_0)$ doesn’t make sense because the input to $S$ should be a vector, whereas $z_0$ is a scalar.

Comment: Here is a partial answer to (3). The Jacobian matrix is essentially the definition of the multivariate derivative. Heuristically, the derivative of a single variable function $f$ at a point $x$ is the "best" choice of $m$ so that $f(t) \approx m(t-x)+f(x)$ for $t$ in a neighborhood of $x$. The natural generalization of this to multiple dimensions is that the derivative of a multivariate function $f$ is the "best" matrix $A$ so that $f(x) \approx A(t-x) + f(x)$ for $t$ in a neighborhood of $x$. It can be proven that the matrix $m$ obeying this property is the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: Let $A=\operatorname{Diag}(a),{\rm\;then\;}{\large\frac{\partial a}{\partial z}} = A-aa^T\;$ is a nicer expression for the gradient